# HTML.DisplayFor method using string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, displayfor

In my ASP.Net MVC appication I have a loop which i'd like to display different Properties values in HTML using the HTML.DisplayFor method. But it will not accept a string value to direct to the Model parameter.

Normal mode:

```
<img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Image_1)" />
```

My loop:

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        string currentImage = "Model.Image_" + i;
        if ((@Html.DisplayFor(model => "Model.Image_" + i ).ToString()) != "")
        {
            <div>
                <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => currentImage)" />
            </div>
        }

    }
```

My results in the `img src` are just `currentImage`.
I'd like it to be `Model.Image_" + i`.
How would I do that?

If you have a better way of doing this that would be appreciated as well.
Should my images have their own Model -class, you think?

Comment: Delete the `if` block (that makes no sense) and just use `string currentImage = "Image_" + i; <img src="@Html.Display(currentImage)" />` but all this suggests a design problem. You should have a `IEnumerable<string> Images` property containing the image paths

Comment: The if block is to not add HTML if the property would be empty ( "" ). Thank you for the ideas

Comment: You clearly have a major design flaw if you really have properties `Image_1`, `Image_2` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of a property dynamically using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) like this.

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    string imagePropName= "Image_" + i;
    string imageSrc = Model.GetType().GetProperty(imagePropName).GetValue(Model) as string;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageSrc))
    {
        <div>
            <img src="@Url.Content(imageSrc)" />
        </div>
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be to write `<img src="@Url.Content(Model.Image_1)`, `<img src="@Url.Content(Model.Image_2) />` 10 times. I mean if you have created 10 properties, might as well be consistent with the implementation.

But as stephen said, just get a `List` of ImagePaths and loop through them in your `View`. If the requirement changes to displaying 20 images, you'd have to add 10 more properties.

Comment: Thank you that is billiant! Solved and +1